# need to creat Pie Gauge Chart in Julia

Tags: plot, julia

I need to design a Pie Gauge Chart for each JOB category. My data look like

```
 BR PROG_JOB1 PROG_JOB2 PROG_JOB3
0 BR1 0.5 0.4 0.5
1 BR2 0.3 0.2 0.6
2 BR3 0.6 0.5 0.3
```

and I need to create Circular Gauge for each JOB progress. How should I do it in Julia

I have tried [https://lumiamitie.github.io/r/pie-gauge-in-ggplot2/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)  by `proj=:polar` in Plots.jl, but doesn't solve it.

desired output
[image]

Comment: you linked to an `R` library, so of course the options don't work for Julia. As far as I know, there's no way to do this in Python or Julia out-of-the-box

Comment: @GoFORIT How did you produce your output?

Comment: manually in Microsoft Excel!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `StatisticalGraphics` package:

```
using InMemoryDatasets
using StatisticalGraphics
ds=Dataset(BR=["BR1","BR2","BR3"],JOB1=[.5,.3,.6],JOB2=[.4,.2,.5],JOB3=[.5,.6,.3])

# data manipulation
ds2=transpose(gatherby(ds,:BR),r"JOB")
modify!(ds2,:_c1=>byrow(x->[x,1-x])=>:progress,:BR=>byrow(x->[x,missing])=>:cat)
flatten!(ds2,[:progress,:cat])

# plot
sgplot(
      groupby(ds2,:_variables_),
      Pie(category=:cat,response=:progress,group=:BR,innerradius=0.3, label=:percent,labelcolor=:white,colormodel=[:blue,:white,:orange,:green]),
      layout=:row,headercolname=false,legend=false,width=200,height=200
      )
```

[image: plot]

Comment: thank you very much. how I can add BR1,BR2,BR3 to each progress?

Comment: Maybe adding another pie chart only for labels, change `Pie(...)` to `[Pie(category=:cat, response=:progress, group=:BR, innerradius=0.3, label=:percent, labelcolor=:white, colormodel=[:blue,:white,:orange,:green]), Pie(category=:cat,group=:BR,label=:category,colormodel=[:white], innerradius=0.3,endangle=-0.0001, labelalign=:right)]`

Answer (score 0):

You can draw it manually with `GLMakie`:

```
using GLMakie
pie([0.5, 0.5], color=[:green, :white], inner_radius=0.8, strokecolor=:white)
pie!([0.3, 0.7], color=[:orange, :white], inner_radius=0.6, radius=0.79, strokecolor=:white)
pie!([0.6, 0.4], color=[:blue, :white], inner_radius=0.4, radius=0.59, strokecolor=:white)
```

[image: makie_output]